# What inner autmorphism really do in abstract algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

The definition of inner automorphism is easy to understand but I wonder what these inner automorphism really do in abstract Lie algebra, especially when we are talking about Lie algebra ?

In Lie group analysis inner automorphism are also known to be adjoint actions and are used to classify Lie algebra into optimal subalgebra(please refer to example 3.10 of [Olver book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387950006)). Using "Differential Geometry" and "Lie Algebra" package of [Maple](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/dg/) these adjoint actions(or inner automorphism) can be easily calculated for finite dimensional Lie algebra. But when it comes to infinite dimensional Lie algebra(where arbitrary functions occurs in algebra) finding inner automorphism is not an easy task(See [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1007570404001546) table 2). I really do not have any idea how author has constructed such inner automorphism from infinite Lie algebra given at (7)-(8).